# ACF relationship field by user

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Trying to query posts were the current user is set in a user relationship field. Thought it would be easy but I am totally stuck.
I have tried this:

```
<?php 
    $user = new WP_User(get_current_user_id());
    $posts = get_field('consultora', 'user_'.$user->ID);
    if( $posts ): 
?>
    <div class="assistente-foto">
        <?php foreach( $posts as $post):?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <?php echo the_post_thumbnail();?>
            <p><strong><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></strong></p>
            <p>t. <?php the_field('telefone'); ?></p>
            <p>e. <?php the_field('email'); ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

[caption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A819L.png)

Comment: So, you have a relationship field in your user profile (with ID: "consultora"), and you want to query that field. Does $posts contain the array you want? (So do you get the data with get_field()?)

Comment: When you are looking for user data in WP, you should check if the user is logged in or not - so I would put the whole thing in a is_user_logged_in() conditional - just to be sure, that I should get the user data.